# App styling shows on local host but not on deployed Heroku (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, heroku, http-status-code-404

This is my first time deploying one of my Web Apps with Heroku and I am having this problem where the CSS styling is not showing up. When I look at the app on Local Host the CSS is there.

I'm getting a 404 Error for the output.css file when I inspect the Heroku site.

Here is my public/index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Cosmetics</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/output.css" />
        <script defer src="/bundle.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my Server/App.js file:

```
const path = require('path')
const express = require('express')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const app = express()
module.exports = app

// logging middleware
app.use(morgan('dev'))

// body parsing middleware
app.use(express.json())

// auth and api routes
app.use('/auth', require('./auth'))
app.use('/api', require('./api'))

app.get('/', (req, res)=> res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public/index.html')));

// static file-serving middleware
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public')))

// any remaining requests with an extension (.js, .css, etc.) send 404
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (path.extname(req.path).length) {
    const err = new Error('Not found')
    err.status = 404
    next(err)
  } else {
    next()
  }
})

// sends index.html
app.use('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public/index.html'));
})

// error handling endware
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.error(err)
  console.error(err.stack)
  res.status(err.status || 500).send(err.message || 'Internal server error.')
})
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "cosmetics",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "description": "Build a brand new cosmetic shopping experience!",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "build:dev": "npm run build -- --watch --mode=development",
    "seed": "node seed.js",
    "start": "node server",
    "start:dev": "npm run watch:css && npm run build:dev & npm run start-server",
    "start:dev:logger": "LOGGING=true npm run start:dev",
    "start:dev:seed": "SEED=true npm run start:dev",
    "start-server": "JWT=shh nodemon server -e html,js,scss --ignore public --ignore client",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test JWT=a_secret mocha \"./server/**/*.spec.js\" \"./client/**/*.spec.js\" --require @babel/register --require esm ",
    "test:dev": "npm run test -- --watch",
    "test:dev:models": "npm run test:dev -- --grep=model",
    "test:dev:routes": "npm run test:dev -- --grep=route",
    "watch:css": "postcss public/style.css -o public/output.css"
  },
  "author": "Fullstack Academy of Code",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.3",
    "@material/card": "^14.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "chalk": "^2.4.1",
    "compression": "^1.7.3",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "history": "^4.9.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "material-table": "1.36.0",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "pg": "^8.5.1",
    "react-simple-image-slider": "^2.4.1",
    "sequelize": "^6.3.5",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.4",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "postcss-cli": "^9.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/register": "^7.12.10",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.16.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.9.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.12.1",
    "esm": "^3.2.25",
    "mocha": "^6.2.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.16",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-redux": "^7.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.4.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.5",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.3",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "supertest": "^4.0.2",
    "webpack": "^5.15.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.3.1"
  }
}
```

If anyone has any ideas or solutions they would be appreciated. I'm sure it's a simple connection issue of some sort, but I've been debugging it for hours and have been unable to sort it out.

Comment: You could try moving the static files middle-ware above the GET route. There's a possibility that the GET matches and returns before it gets to the middle-ware.

Comment: @BenzStevox Unfortunately that did not work.